# Can't print the value of models.ManyToManyField always return None

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to print the Value of ManyToManyField to the template but it always returns accounts.Product.None, I think ManyToManyField returns a list! but still don't know how to output it

```
{{order.product}}
```

models

```
class Product(models.Model):

name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tags)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name




class Order(models.Model):
product = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

view

```
def home(request):
products = Product.objects.all()
orders = Order.objects.all()

context = {'total_orders': total_orders,
           'orders': orders
           }

return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html', context)
```

template

```
          {% for order in orders %}
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">{{order.id}}</th>
              <td>{{order.product}}</td>
              <td>{{order.date_created}}</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          {% endfor %}
```

Comment: the for loop isn't initiated due to missing space `{% for order in orders %}`

Comment: thank you i missed it when i was cleaning the code to put it here, still didn't fix the issue

Comment: Does your context return any objects in `orders` ?

Comment: yes it reture all here  orders = Order.objects.all()

Comment: did you try `{{ order.product }}`?

Comment: yes it returns accounts.Product.None

Comment: Have you created any products for those orders so that they return anything other than None?

Comment: @GProst yes sure i have products in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change template like this:

```
      {% for order in orders %}
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">{{order.id}}</th>
          <td>{% for product in product.order.all %}
            <li>{{ product }}</li>
            {% endfor %}</td>
          <td>{{order.date_created}}</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
```